# PMD issue as null pointer exception

Tags: java, pmd

I have a jar file created for multiple Apex custom rules with a maven pom.
My src/main/java folder contains 8 java programs.
I have created a jar file out of it, but am not sure when the jar gets executed which class will get executed? I want to run the analysis by the single jar file
When I run this with pmd.bat command, I get null pointer exception as jar is unable to get which main class to be invoked first to run the analysis

Comment: An executable jar has the main class specified in its manifest. Alternatively, you can specify the jar as classpath and specify the main class on the Java command line.

Comment: Hello, I have 8 custom rules written now and am not sure which mainclass should I mention in manifest section..as I want all the classes to get invoked...I execute the jar by placing in the lib folder of pmd installation. Previously I have written one rule and I have included that class name in main class in manifest section and when I ran the pmd bat. It worked

Comment: can u help me with suggestion on how I can have all these classes included in a single jar file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check in your `.jar`, the file `META-INF/MANIFEST.MD`, which class is referenced in `Main-Class` key. If you have any, you can specify it at runtime with `java -jar myjar.jar com.test.Main` (if your class is `com.test.Main`).

However, it would be better to specify it directly in the MANIFEST.MD, through for example a maven plugin

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        ...
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Hello, I have 8  custom rules written now and am not sure which mainclass should I mention in manifest section..as I want all the classes to get invoked...I execute the jar by placing in the lib folder of pmd installation. Previously I have written one rule and I have included that class name in main class in manifest section and when I ran the pmd bat. It worked.

Comment: You can always implement a "Main" class that'll chose between the 8 based on argv, or just loop on all 8 !

Comment: Thanks Jonathan..I guess this would help..let me try

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you want to do the following:

- You have created custom [PMD](https://pmd.github.io) rules for the Apex language.
- You want to compile the custom rules.
- You want to create a custom PMD distribution, which contains all the stock rules and your custom rules, so that you can easily install it and use it

For this, please have a look a the example project (https://github.com/pmd/pmd-examples) - especially the example for java: https://github.com/pmd/pmd-examples/tree/java
It might be a bit outdated and you need to adjust it for apex, but it describes the two options you have (either using a custom distribution or just copying your custom rules jar into the lib folder).

Once you have integrated your custom rules in your PMD installation, you your rules are available when you execute PMD.

Comment: Hi adangel, I have a query..is there any restriction for custom jar name? because I have prefixed it with my company's name and the jar didn't work...but as soon as I have removed it..the jar started working